# why assembled executable size is the same

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, instructions

In x86_64 architecture it is possible to change some instruction-operands combinations with shorter ones to achieve the same effect, but smaller executable.
for example, it is common to write:

```
xor eax, eax
```

instead of:

```
xor rax, rax
```

I wanted to test it, wrote simple program in assembly:

```
    segment .text
    global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    xor rax, rax ; line in question
    leave
    ret
```

built:

```
yasm -f elf64 -m amd64 -g dwarf2 main.asm; clang -o main main.o
```

checked size:

```
stat main
```

got:

```
....
Size: 9184
...
```

Ok, changed line in question to:

```
xor eax, eax
```

hoping to get smaller executable, but got the same 9184 bytes in size.
Why size did not decrease with using shorter instruction form?

Comment: padding to a 16B boundary before the next function.  Look at disassembler output.

Comment: I did `disassemble` in gdb, got
`0x400re0 <+0>: push %rbp`
`=> 0x4004e4 <+4>: xor %rax, %rax`, it is not at 16 byte boundary nor in case with `xor eax, eax`.

Comment: _"it is not at 16 byte boundary"_ It's not where that instruction begins that matters. The section in which the instruction is located may be padded to be a multiple of X bytes. But like @PeterCordes has already suggested, just look at the generated machine code bytes for the instruction you're interested in using a disassembler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `size` command to find out how large the parts of a binary are. Using `ls` or `stat` is inaccurate as parts of the binary are *padded* to some power of 2 (e.g. to the next multiple of 16).

However, in your case there is still no difference because the text segment from `main.o` is padded to a multiple of 16 bytes after which the startup code `crt0.o` is linked. Thus there is no difference in code size.

Answer (score 6):

When object files are linked together, the linker inserts padding at the end of the .text section of `main.o` so the start of the text section from `crt0.o` begins at a 16B alignment boundary.

If you'd disassembled your binary like I suggested, you'd have seen this:

```
$ objdump -Mintel -drw main
...
0000000000400500 <main>:
  400500:       55                      push   rbp
  400501:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  400504:       48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
  400507:       c9                      leave  
  400508:       c3                      ret    
  400509:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]    <--- padding inserted by linker

0000000000400510 <__libc_csu_init>:
  400510:       41 57                   push   r15
  ...
```

**Changing the size of `main()` will just change the size of the NOP padding, until you pass a 16B boundary.**

---

Interestingly, if you disassemble `main.o`, there's no padding after the `ret`, so I think the NOP must have been inserted by the linker.

Using `readelf -aW main.o` shows:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name       Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
...
  [ 4] .text      PROGBITS        0000000000000000 000040 000009 00  AX  0   0 16
....
```

Without -W, you can see the full column names instead of having them packed on one line.  The last column is "alignment".  This is how yasm would tell the linker that the .text section of that object needed 32B or whatever other alignment inside the text segment of the linker output.

Adding an `ALIGN 4096` before `main:` results in the .o having a 4096 in the alignment column of .text.  It adds NOP padding onto the end of the function *before* `main` in the linked binary, so `main` is at 0x00402000.  This does change the size of the binary.

Comment: I added `align 4096` and now binary increased its size significantly.
Could you please explain, why one may need to use custom alignments instead of default, set by assembler?

Comment: @BulatM.: Maybe you want something page-aligned so you know where the page boundaries are, so you can read outside of an object without causing a page fault.   IDK, there are very many specific reasons why you might want this, usual for performance tuning.  Code alignment has many direct and indirect effect on CPU performance, from the obvious I-cache line boundaries to the less obvious global branch prediction table aliasing.  And no, I'm not going to explain any of that for you, because it would take forever.  Google it up.

Answer (score 3):

Disassembly:

```
31 c0          xor    eax,eax  ; 2 bytes opcode
48 31 c0       xor    rax,rax  ; 3 bytes opcode
```

Executable file contains many other things (as explained in comments from others), and your code may also in total remain the same, as next code may be aligned by additional `nop`. Don't expect the file size will react to every byte of opcode shaved off.